# GIT Merge: Merge files where different additions were made on the same lines in separate branches

Tags: git, version-control, azure-devops

We are in the early development phases of a massive update for a code base.  The work currently involves adding a lot of functions to certain files.  The problem we are currently running into is a Developer from our main Dev branch (Branch A) creates a branch (Branch B) and completes one user story that involves adding a function to a certain file and submits a pull request to merge with Branch A.
The developer then moves on to the next user story while waiting for the pull request to be approved and create Branch C from Branch A and adds code to the same file he did in Branch B (Since Branch C came from A the code from B is not present yet).  Upon submitting the pull request for Branch C a conflict occurs because the merge manager assume you are trying the same code in both branches

```
 B--PR----
/        \    
A--------D--------E(Conflict)
    \            /
     C----------PR
```

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you provided, by the time branch `C` is ready to be merged, the PR from branch `B` has been approved and merged. You're being warned about a merge conflict for a really good reason: There **is** a merge conflict. This is common, expected, and totally normal. There's nothing to prevent.

You solve it by merging the latest from branch `A` into branch `C` and resolving conflicts manually, then pushing a new commit that will merge into `A` cleanly.